# Let $T:V\rightarrow W$ a linear transformation, $i_w:W\rightarrow W^{**}$ and $i_v:V\rightarrow V^{**}$ canonical morphism of biduality.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\rightarrow W$ a linear transformation, $i_w:W\rightarrow W^{**}$ and $i_v:V\rightarrow V^{**}$ canonical morphism of biduality.

Prove $i_w\circ T=T^{**}\circ i_v$

I' m very very confused with this exercise.

Suppose i need to prove this:

$i_w\circ T\subset T^{**}\circ i_v$ and $T^{**}\circ i_v\subset i_w\circ T $ but  i don't have idea of how to prove this. Can somone give me a hint?

Comment: I think you must be confused - these are *functions* so the statement $i_w\circ T \subseteq T^{**}\circ i_v$ makes no sense. Rather, the explicit thing you need to show is that $i_w(T(x))=T^{**}(i_v(x))$ for all $x\in V$. This is straightforwards if you can write down an explicit form for each function (the main difficulty here being that the double dual can be kind of a confusing space)

Answer (score 2):

Let's recall the definitions: if $T : V \to W$, then $T^{*} : W^* \to V^*$ is a linear map defined as $T^{*}(f) = f \circ T$ for all $f \in W^*$.

Then, $T^{**} : V^{**} \to W^{**}$ is defined as $T^{**}(g) = g\circ T$ for all $g \in V^{**}$.

Now, to prove $i_w\circ T=T^{**}\circ i_v$ let's first establish the domain and codomain of both sides. Since $T : V \to W$ and $i_W : W \to W^{**}$, we have $i_w\circ T : V \to W^{**}$. Similarly, since $i_v : V \to V^{**}$ and $T^{**} : V^{**} \to W^{**}$, we have $T^{**}\circ i_v : V \to W^{**}$, so both sides represent a function with the same domain and codomain.

Let $x \in V$ be arbitrary. Let's show that $ (i_w\circ T)(x)= (T^{**}\circ i_v)(x)$. This is an equality of two functions $W^* \to \mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is the underlying field of your vector spaces. Therefore take an arbitrary $f \in W^*$, and let's show $ (i_v\circ T)(x)(f)= (T^{**}\circ i_v)(x)(f)$ in $\mathbb{F}$.

\begin{align}(i_w\circ T)(x)(f) &= (i_w(T(x))(f)\\
&= f(T(x))\\
&= (f\circ T)(x)\\
&= (i_v(x))(f\circ T)\\
&= (i_v(x))(T^*(f))\\
&= (i_v(x) \circ T^*)(f)\\
&= (T^{**}(i_v(x))(f)\\
&= (T^{**}\circ i_v)(x)(f)\\
\end{align}

Hence, $i_w\circ T=T^{**}\circ i_v$.

Comment: Grax mechanodroid! i will be very grateful to you! very thanks, i was very stressed for this....

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand this part of your proof "This is an equality of two functions $W^* \to \mathbb{F}$" why you say that?

Comment: @Bvss12 $i_w\circ T$ and $T^{**}\circ i_v$ are both functions $V \to W^{**}$. If you pass $x \in V$ as an argument to them, you obtain an element of $W^{**}$. Elements of $W^{**}$ are functions $W^* \to \mathbb{F}$, by definition. To check equality of two functions, you have to check the outputs are equal for all possible inputs.

Comment: true, true thanks for that mechanodroid!